# No icon with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a application that executes normally. But when I make a setup file with Inno Setup no icon is displayed. The setup script is:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.

; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName       "MyApp"
#define MyAppVersion    "1.0"
#define MyAppExeName    "MyApp.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{C1DD3B91-BDCD-45CC-BFCA-C52DD39A6631}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName=C:\Inno Setup Studio\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputDir=C:\Inno Setup Studio\MyApp
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "Do you want to create desktop icon?"; Flags: checkablealone

[Files]
Source: "C:\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

Source: "Requirements\msvcp100.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\msvcp100d.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\msvcr100.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\msvcr100d.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\PocoFoundation.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\PocoFoundationd.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\QtCore4.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\QtCored4.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\QtGui4.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\QtGuid4.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\QtNetwork4.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\QtNetworkd4.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Requirements\QtService.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"


[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram, #StringChange(MyAppName, '&','&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: Because your script lacks [Icons] section. Example for desktop shortcut `[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyAppName"; Filename: "{app}\MyAppExeName.EXE"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Tasks: desktopicon` (with `; IconFileName: "{app}\MyAppIconFile.ico"` if needed)

Comment: Just to clarify, which icon(s) are you actually talking about?

Comment: @Deanna - From the code you can predict it is about `[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"` - sheykholeslam check the checkbox on Task Page, but no Icon is created on the desktop as `[Icons]` section is missing from the script.

Comment: Off-topic, but note that typically you should not be installing the debug versions of libraries.

Comment: to clarify, in the application (the one installed by inno setup) none of the icons is shown. Additionally, I added the [Icon] section and it doesn't solve the problem. ?????

Comment: @RobeN I assumed it was the lack of application icons on the start menu. I was asking the OP to be explicit rather than expecting us to guess what their problem is.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old post.  But maybe this will help someone.

With inno, using something like the following, I was able to associate icons with the desktop shortcut(desktop.ico), the app launched from start(start.ico), the uninstall launched from start(uninst.ico), and the setup.exe(setup.ico).

Substitute your icon paths\names in place of e.g. C:\Temp\setup.ico.  Substitute your app in place of MyApp.

In the [Setup] section:

```
SetupIconFile=C:\Temp\setup.ico
```

In the [Icons] section:

```
Name: "{group}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename: "C:\Temp\start.ico"

Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,MyApp}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; IconFilename: "C:\Temp\uninst.ico"

Name: "{commondesktop}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon; IconFilename: "C:\Temp\desktop.ico"
```

Comment: YES THANK YOUUUUU.

Answer (score 3):

Looking on your script I can say that there is [Icons] section missing. You have added [Tasks] with checkbox for Desktop Icon only.

You should add to your script something like:

```
[Icons] 
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyAppName"; Filename: "{app}\MyAppExeName.EXE";
 WorkingDir: "{app}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

If the EXE file does not contain Icon or if you want to set you custom icon, you should additionally use flag: `IconFileName: "{app}\CustomIconFile.ico"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifically looking for the icon used when listing the install in the list under the *Add/Remove Program* section of the configuration panel, use the [`UninstallDisplayIcon`](http://www.innosetup.com/ishelp/topic_setup_uninstalldisplayicon.htm) setting.

Answer (score 0):

The space character in the name of the directory where the icon file is located may be causing this problem. If the icon file is under, for example, the 'my images' directory, the program does not see it. You can try not using unacceptable characters such as spaces in the directory name.